# d3 v4 Why can't I get my x axis and bars to line up?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, data-visualization

I've got as far as making my bar chart with an x axis but can't work out why I can't get the bars and the tick spacing on the x axis to line up exactly. At the moment the ticks are slightly to the right of center of the bar.

csv file example:

```
crop,records
CASSAVA,350
MAIZE,226
TOMATOES,137
```

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Abbie's attempt at D3</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        svg {
            background-color: rgba(227, 227, 227, 0.97);
            }
        .bar {
            margin: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 40};
            var w = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
            var h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            var barPadding = 5;
            var cropData;

    // load the csv file
    d3.csv("crops.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.records = +d.records;
        });
        cropData = data;

        var arrayLength = cropData.length;
        var yMax = d3.max(cropData, function(d) {
                return d.records;
        });

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([0, yMax])
                            .range([h, 0]);

        var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                        .domain(cropData.map(function(d) {
                            return d.crop;
                        }))
                        .rangeRound([0, w]);

        // create the svg
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // bars
        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(cropData)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * xScale.bandwidth() + 5;
                })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.records);
                })
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth() - 5)
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d.records);
                })
            .attr("fill", "teal")
            .attr("class", "bar");

        // x Axis
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", ".15em")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "rotate(-60)"
                    });

        // y Axis
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
        svg.append("g")
            .call(yAxis);

    </script>
</body>
```

Am I doing it right with `i * xScale.bandwidth() + 5` and `xScale.bandwidth() - 5` in the `x` and `width` attributes of `rect` or is this not the correct way to do it? How do I change the spacing of the ticks on the x axis if I change the bars? They both use `xScale` so I feel it must be something to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make the following changes.

First, introduce a `padding` to your `xScale`:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(cropData.map(function(d) {
    return d.crop;
  }))
  .rangeRound([0, w])
  .padding(0.1);
```

This will space the bars by a percent of the bandWidth.

Second, place your bars using your `xScale`:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(cropData)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.crop); //<-- place by xScale
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.records);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth()) //<-- no -5 padding takes care of breaks
```

Runnable code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Abbie's attempt at D3</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    svg {
      background-color: rgba(227, 227, 227, 0.97);
    }
    
    .bar {
      margin: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 30,
      bottom: 100,
      left: 40
    };
    var w = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var barPadding = 5;
    var cropData;

    // load the csv file
    //d3.csv("crops.csv", function(error, data) {

      var data = [{
        "crop": "CASSAVA",
        "records": "350"
      }, {
        "crop": "MAIZE",
        "records": "226"
      }, {
        "crop": "TOMATOES",
        "records": "137"
      }];

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.records = +d.records;
      });
      cropData = data;

      var arrayLength = cropData.length;
      var yMax = d3.max(cropData, function(d) {
        return d.records;
      });

      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, yMax])
        .range([h, 0]);

      var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(cropData.map(function(d) {
          return d.crop;
        }))
        .rangeRound([0, w])
        .padding(0.1);

      // create the svg
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      // bars
      svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(cropData)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return xScale(d.crop);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return yScale(d.records);
        })
        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return h - yScale(d.records);
        })
        .attr("fill", "teal")
        .attr("class", "bar");

      // x Axis
      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(-60)"
        });

      // y Axis
      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
      svg.append("g")
        .call(yAxis);
        
   // });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! A combination of wrong things was messing it all up! It's looking good now :-)